# How can I watch for newly created files and wait for them to be unlocked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First the watch method; I need to watch for any newly created jpg files, since I don't know yet the file names. My program creates each time a new jpg in the directory specified by a TextBox. So my first problem is how to know/get the file name when it's being created?

Second problem, how can I use all these methods, the two methods and the event changed (code below)? I have a button click event when I click it, it will create the new jpg file. Then in the button click event I want to start watching it and give a message on a label something like: "Creating file wait", then when the file is created and ready for use "File created".

```
private void watch()
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = SavePathTextBox.Text;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    watcher.Filter = "*.jpg";
    watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

Then the event `watcher_Changed`:

```
void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{

}
```

And the method that checks if the file is locked or not

```
public static bool IsFileReady(String sFilename)
{
    // If the file can be opened for exclusive access it means that the file
    // is no longer locked by another process.
    try
    {
        using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(sFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            if (inputStream.Length > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is what i tried:

In the button click event:

```
private void TakePhotoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((string)TvCoBox.SelectedItem == "Bulb") CameraHandler.TakePhoto((uint)BulbUpDo.Value);
                else CameraHandler.TakePhoto();
                watch();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { ReportError(ex.Message, false); }
        }
```

In the watch method:

```
private void watch()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = SavePathTextBox.Text;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Filter = "*.JPG";
            watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
```

The event watcher_Changed

```
void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsFileReady(e.FullPath) == false)
            {
                this.Invoke((Action)delegate { label6.Text = "Busy"; });
            }
            else
            {
                this.Invoke((Action)delegate { label6.Text = "File Ready"; }); 
            }
        }
```

And the method to find if file is locked or not:

```
public static bool IsFileReady(String sFilename)
        {
            // If the file can be opened for exclusive access it means that the file
            // is no longer locked by another process.
            try
            {
                using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(sFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    if (inputStream.Length > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that sometimes in most of the cases it's getting to the line inside the watcher_Changed event:

```
this.Invoke((Action)delegate { label6.Text = "File Ready"; });
```

And making this line twice or somtimes even 3 times in a row.
I can say that each click my camera take one photo and it's creating two files one for example with the name: IMG_0001.CR2 and the Jpg one: IMG_0001.JPG

But i'm not sure if that's why it's getting to the event and doing the line/s there more then once.

I also checked the file in the e.FullPath is always .jpg and never cr2.
The question is why it's getting there more then once and how can i make sure that the file is really ready ? ("File Ready")

Maybe i need somehow to track the file size from 0kb until the size not change any more and then to decide in the event that it's ready or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems with the way You use watcher.

- Watcher should run before You call `CameraHandler.TakePhoto` or there is a (small) chance You would miss it.
- Either do not create new instance of watcher on every `TakePhotoButton_Click` or stop the old one. Otherwise You would end up with new running watcher with every click and get as many calls to `watcher_Changed` as many watchers You have.
- I have read there is a chance watcher can be garbage collected. I am not sure if it is true, but rather be safe and save it to some local field.

What You are now waiting for is end of writing to some .jpg file. This may do what You need and in that case it is good. But if You want to wait for file create, You need different setting. This worked for me:

```
string watchDir = Application.StartupPath;
watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(watchDir, "*.jpg");
watcher.NotifyFilter |= NotifyFilters.Size;
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Created);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

protected void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    string changeType = e.ChangeType.ToString();
    if (changeType != "Created")
    {
        return;
    }

    // file is created, wait for IsFileReady or whatever You need
}
```